# Where can I find an official docs about private and public keys' generation?

Tags: wallet, address, private-key, public-key, eddsa

Is there an official documentation showing us a process of creation of `private` key, `public` key (including EdDSA math), and wallet `address`, with examples written in Python or C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page is pretty good with the cli commands needed for doing this: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet

I remember seeing some examples in Python that just made calls to these cli commands via the shell module and parsed the results. There is also a [cardano-python](https://github.com/emesik/cardano-python) module being developed you may want to check out.

Or you could try using the [REST API docs](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#tag/Wallets) via the python requests module. You can run this locally by going to the first link I posted and searching for `Starting cardano-wallet as a REST API server`

Comment: Thank you for you answer Matt! Could you tell me, where I can find info on Cardano algorithm EdDSA?